# Metro stack java web services write own serializer/deserializer

Tags: java, web-services, java-metro-framework

I am facing some problem while returning data from web services. 
I am using Metro stack.

**Problem:**  
The problem is my data contain some control characters. I don't want to encrypt my data, as this will involve client side code changes as well. 
Better way is to remove control characters, but character by characters scanning and removing/replaceAll will have some performance impact.

**Probable solution:** 
What I want to do is intercept SOAP message before metro send it to client and check control characters. And then replace all control characters of XML before returning.

Do anyone here have any idea how can I intercept response before returning? Or 
how I can write my own serializer/deserializer where I can replace control char?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found XMLAdapter very useful in my case.
Adding info as in case any buddy can find it useful. 
Reference: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html

XMLAdapter contain abstract method marshal and unmarshal. So I used appropriate encoder in marshal/unmarshal method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the [Provider](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/Provider.html) interface to do this. Your implementation of the provider would be called instead of the actual web service. Then you would parse the XML and forward the call to you service implementation.

I find it somewhat cumbersome to work with, but if it works..